# Error: missing read template file (hjs)

Tags: node.js, templating, hogan.js

I'm learning NodeJS and I'm having some problem with hjs.

[This is the code](https://pastebin.com/2JXQg2MD)

and below is the error being generated:

```
 Error: missing read template file : H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\views\users.hjs
    at Object.Hogan.fcompile (H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\node_modules\hjs\lib\express.js:48:10)
    at View.Hogan.renderFile [as engine] (H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\node_modules\hjs\lib\express.js:76:19)
    at View.render (H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:127:8)
    at tryRender (H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:971:7)
    at db.then (H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\server.js:25:17)
    at tryCatcher (H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (H:\Users\stuffs\tutorials\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:800:20)
```

also here the hjs file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        {{title}}
    </title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        </div>
        {{#users}}
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/viewtweets/{{id}}">{{username}}</a></li>
        </ul>   
        {{/#users}}
    </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

thank you! 
i know it might be something stupid but i'm stuck with this error and i couldnt find any solutions online.

Comment: Try to set 'view' property on express like this `app.set('views',__dirname+ '/views');`